# vb.net 2010 how can I print the contents of a panel?

Tags: vb.net

I have a panel with different attributes such as label, textbox, etc. I want to ask how can I print the contents of this panel? 
thanks all help are appreciated

Comment: examine the panel's `Controls` array.   http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Outputting to a console or like print out on the printer?
You can iterate through the controls inside a panel like this:

```
Dim panelControl As System.Windows.Forms.Control
For Each panelControl In Me.Panel1.Controls
    Console.WriteLine(panelControl.Text)
Next
```